# Issue while adding arguments

Tags: services

I am adding one argument to the custom service named "streamtype" as follows

```
function CMODULE_services_resources() {
  $api = array(
    'oidar' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'retrieve' => array(
          'help' => 'Retrieves All oidar operations',
          'callback' => '_CMODULE_blog_retrieve',
          'access callback' => 'user_access',
          'access arguments' => array('access content'),
          'access arguments append' => FALSE,
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'fn',
              'type' => 'string',
              'description' => 'Function to perform',
              'source' => array('path' => '0'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'uid',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => 'Number of latest items to get',
              'source' => array('param' => 'uid'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '1',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'nid',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => 'Posts from the last number of days',
              'source' => array('param' => 'nid'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'counter',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => 'counter view',
              'source' => array('param' => 'counter'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'id',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => 'node id for display',
              'source' => array('param' => 'id'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'view',
              'type' => 'int',
              'description' => 'view counter',
              'source' => array('param' => 'view'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'title',
              'type' => 'string',
              'description' => 'title',
              'source' => array('param' => 'title'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'body',
              'type' => 'string',
              'description' => 'body',
              'source' => array('param' => 'body'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'type',
              'type' => 'string',
              'description' => 'type',
              'source' => array('param' => 'type'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),  
            array(
              'name' => 'iso3',
              'type' => 'string',
              'description' => 'Country',
              'source' => array('param' => 'iso3'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '',
            ),
            array(
              'name' => 'streamtype',
              'type' => 'string',
              'description' => 'Stream Type',
              'source' => array('param' => 'streamtype'),
              'optional' => TRUE,
              'default' => '0',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $api;
}
```

But I am not getting streamtype (getting empy) when I try to access that further in code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer after trying many things. I just cleared the cache and it worked!

I hope this helps somebody else.

Thanks,
Kunal